# Python module generator for github

Tags: python, python-module

I'm newbie to python and it's philosophy. I'm trying to develop a module on github. Is there any Ruby's gem generator like tool for developing module? How to develop a module? Thank you for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a tool to create a python module, any filename ending in `.py` is sufficient.  A *package*, which is a collection of modules, is similarly created by the presence of a file named `__init__.py` in the same folder as other modules (and possibly other packages).  The `__init__.py` file can be empty or not, your choice.

Best practices dictate that importing a module should have no side effects; It should define classes and functions, but take no action.  python modules should start with a docstring explaining the purpose of the module and how it should be used.

Comment: Thank you for educate me. Did you know good example of python module on github?

Comment: There's nothing in particular you need to do to use github to host python source code.  Just follow the directions on [github Bootcamp](http://help.github.com/) to set up git and create a repo, then just do all of your coding in the same folder that you used `git init`.